# Cannot get rid of assembly load error under IIS - works fine in development server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

As an intermediate deployment step, we are trying to deploy a simple MVC 4 application to my local iis 7 instance, and I continue to get this assembly load error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The DLLs in the folder under iis are copied from the development project folder, as is the web.config file.  I do not understand the binding redirects on these files in the web.config file, I'm guessing the problem has something to do with that, but it works fine when run from Visual Studio 2012.  Here is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

 <configSections>
    <section name="protectedSettings" 
                  type="Payx.InstantPayroll.Entities.Configuration.ProtectedSettings, Payx.InstantPayroll.Entities"/>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"                           
                  requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add name="IPEncryptionProvider" 
               type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" 
               keyContainerName="IPKeyContainer" useMachineContainer="true" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>

  <!-- protected settings section removed for posting purposes -->

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TestMvcDeployAgain-20140206101736.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestMvcDeployAgain-20140206101736;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Imaging" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                     allowCookies="false"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferSize="100000000" maxBufferPoolSize="100000000"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000"
                     messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"
                     transferMode="Buffered"
                     useDefaultWebProxy="true">
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                             maxArrayLength="100000000"
                             maxBytesPerRead="65536"
                             maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
               <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                             proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                           algorithmSuite="Default" />
               </security>
            </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>

            <behavior name="AddImpCert">
               <clientCredentials>
                  <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                      storeName="TrustedPeople"
                      x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                      findValue="eip-imaging-user"/>
               </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>

            <behavior name="AddImpCertProd">
               <clientCredentials>
                  <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                      storeName="TrustedPeople"
                      x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                      findValue="eip-img-user"/>
               </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>            

         </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <client>
         <endpoint address="https://webservicesimp.paychex.com/imaging"
             behaviorConfiguration="AddImpCert"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Imaging"
             contract="OrsService.IEnterpriseImagingService"
             name="Orsweb-dev" />

         <endpoint address="https://webservicesimp.paychex.com/imaging"
             behaviorConfiguration="AddImpCert"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Imaging"
             contract="OrsService.IEnterpriseImagingService"
             name="Orsweb-qa" />

         <endpoint address="https://webservices.paychex.com/imaging"
             behaviorConfiguration="AddImpCertProd"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Imaging"
             contract="OrsService.IEnterpriseImagingService"
             name="Orsweb-prod" />

      </client>

   </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">

      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." 
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule"
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32"
           responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." 
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule"
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
           responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
          type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

The reason for all the extra content is that we are attempting to merge an MVC 4 app with an older application that is a mixture of ASP.NET and classic ASP.  The bulk of the non-MVC-related content if for that portion of the system.

I don't understand why, if the DLLs in the iis folder are identical to the ones from the development project folder, how the "manifest does not match the assembly reference", since the sections of the web.config referencing them are also directly from that project.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes: with what web server technology is the website in the "development folder" running? IIS Express? Visual Studio Development Server?

Based on the error message, my gut is that the DLLs in the bin folder deployed to IIS are NOT the correct version. As I read it, your web config is telling IIS to use version 4.1.0.0. If I was in your shoes, I would continue to investigate why/where there is a DLL version mismatch. Sorry I can't be of further help at the moment.

Comment: Don't waste any more time on this one, we have discovered that my iis install is totally hosed up and not working properly.  Thanks anyway.